# How to stop embedded MPMoviePlayerViewController from hiding statusBar

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've got an embedded MPMoviePlayerViewController within the help-section of my application, playing a video which instructs the user on how to operate certain parts of said application.

however, I couldn't find out how to prevent the MoviePlayer to hide the statusbar once the video starts playing, leading to strange status-bar visibility states.

Does any one of you know how to have the status-bar not fade away upon playing a movie?

thanks for any tipps and tricks in advance,

sam

Answer (score 0):

I'll say sub-class MPMoviePlayerViewController and create your own class, in viewDidLoad method write

> ```
>     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
> ```

This might solve it. Try it!